# Creating form dynamically in Javascript not able to find POST variable on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

In the Js file I create the form dynamically. I'm not showing the complete file, but it's composed by a set of cards. Then on the php file, which is reached once the submit button is pressed, I'm not able to see the POST variable. It's weird cause I can reach the php, so the form is working, but it do not set the post variable. Is somebody able to help me?

NOTE:
I've already tried using Ajax but I had the same problem, reaching the page but not seeing the post variable set.

Js File

```
   var f = document.createElement("form");
   f.setAttribute("method","post");
   f.setAttribute("action","../pages/show_negozio.php");

   var i = document.createElement("input"); 
   i.setAttribute("type","hidden");
   i.setAttribute("value","'.$_SESSION['result_array'][$x+3].'");
   i.setAttribute("name","email");
   i.setAttribute("id","email'.$x.'");


   var s = document.createElement("input"); 
   s.className = ("btn btn-primary");
   s.setAttribute("type","submit");

   f.appendChild(i);
   f.appendChild(s);

   cardFooterDiv.appendChild(f);
```

PHP file

```
<?php
        $name = $POST['email'];
        echo "<p>".$name."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: should be $_POST['email'] instead of $POST['email']

Comment: It was that easy. It worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a little mistake in php file to received "email" in super global variable $_POST.

$POST will be $_POST . underscore is missing.

```
$name = $_POST['email'];
echo "<p>".$name."</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace `$POST` to `$_POST`

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST['email'];
        echo "<p>".$name."</p>";
?>
```